# Maps transformations in scala (computing tags frequencies)

Tags: scala

I'm still not proficient with scala, but I'm using it to process some data, which I read into from a file into the following data structure:

`Map[Id, (Set[Category], Set[Tag])]`

where

```
type Id = String

type Category = String

type Tag = String
```

Essentially, each key in the `Map` is the unique id of an entity that is associated with a set of categories and a set of tags.

My question is: which is the best ( = most **efficient** and most **idiomatic**) way to compute:

- tags frequencies across all entities (`type TagsFrequencies = Map[Tag, Double]`)
- tags frequencies per category (`Map[Category, TagsFrequencies]`)

Here is my attempt:

```
def tagsFrequencies(tags: List[Tag]): TagsFrequencies =
  tags.groupBy(t => t).map(
    kv => (kv._1 -> kv._2.size.toDouble / tags.size.toDouble))

def computeTagsFrequencies(data: Map[Id, (Set[Category], Set[Tag])]): TagsFrequencies = {
  val tags = data.foldLeft(List[Tag]())(
    (acc, kv) => acc ++ kv._2._2.toList)
  tagsFrequencies(tags)
}

def computeTagsFrequenciesPerCategory(data: Map[Id, (Set[Category], Set[Tag])]): Map[Category, TagsFrequencies] = {

  def groupTagsPerCategory(data: Map[Id, (Set[Category], Set[Tag])]): Map[Category, List[Tag]] =
    data.foldLeft(Map[Category, List[Tag]]())(
      (acc, kv) => kv._2._1.foldLeft(acc)(
        (a, category) => a.updated(category, kv._2._2.toList ++ a.getOrElse(category, Set.empty).toList)))

  val tagsPerCategory = groupTagsPerCategory(data)
  tagsPerCategory.map(tpc => (tpc._1 -> tagsFrequencies(tpc._2)))
}
```

As an example, consider

```
val data = Map(
  "id1" -> (Set("c1", "c2"), Set("t1", "t2", "t3")),
  "id2" -> (Set("c1"), Set("t1", "t4")))
```

then:

tags frequencies across all entities is:

```
Map(t3 -> 0.2, t4 -> 0.2, t1 -> 0.4, t2 -> 0.2)
```

and tags frequencies per category is:

```
Map(c1 -> Map(t3 -> 0.2, t4 -> 0.2, t1 -> 0.4, t2 -> 0.2), c2 -> Map(t3 -> 0.3333333333333333, t1 -> 0.3333333333333333, t2 -> 0.3333333333333333))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rewrite for idiom, not necessarily efficiency. I'd make your first method a little more general (the `Iterable` argument), use `identity` instead of `t => t`, and use `mapValues`:

```
def tagsFrequencies(tags: Iterable[Tag]): TagsFrequencies =
  tags.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size / tags.size.toDouble)
```

Because this now takes any `Iterable[Tag]`, you can use it to clean up the second method:

```
def computeTagsFrequencies(data: Map[Id, (Set[Category], Set[Tag])]) =
  tagsFrequencies(data.flatMap(_._2._2))
```

And similarly for the last method:

```
def computeTagsFrequenciesPerCategory(data: Map[Id, (Set[Category], Set[Tag])]) =
  data.values.flatMap {
    case (cs, ts) => cs.map(_ -> ts)
  }.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(v => tagsFrequencies(v.flatMap(_._2)))
```

None of these changes should affect performance in any meaningful way, but you should of course benchmark in your own application.